# How to add content on shopify pages with an app

Tags: shopify

Completely new to shopify app development, I looked around the documentation but I did not find any hint about creating an app that add external content to pages (homepage or product pages or every pages) as countdown apps do on every pages or on product pages.

Any help on it could be a great service !

Answer (score 0):

It is really simple these days:

- create an App, install it in shop
- in app configuration, add an App Proxy
- add a JS callback to the App Proxy using a Script Tag (or however you like)
- have your App return either a full Liquid string response, or JSON
- render response to JS callback in theme

So you can play with this more ways than you can shake a stick. You can return Liquid with your tags so that the web theme designer people can take advantage of what is special about your App. You can just return JSON and template the results into DOM as per the usual pattern.

Comment: How can I know which page has been asked in my proxy to produce different response ? And how I choose where goes the content I respond ?